# Deleting shape in PowerPoint programatically and undoing causes shape to be "lost"

Tags: powerpoint, undo, shapes

(This seems mostly to be a PowerPoint 2007 specific problem, which I can't easily reproduce in PPT 2010)

Easy way to reproduce locally is to:

```
1) Insert a shape into blank slide
2) Run command: ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Delete in immediate window in Visual Studio. (You can alternatively delete through C#)
3) Undo the deletion in the PowerPoint presentation (do this non-programatically)
```

For some reason, you cannot access the shape again using calls like:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1) //Does not allow any methods/properties to work
```

The only thing I've remotely gotten is that through `Selection.ShapeRange`, you can kind of get a reference to the item, but most of the Properties/Methods throw ComExceptions when trying to using that object.

Does anyone know how I can re-get the shape or somehow refresh the presentation to get some clean Com Objects?

Comment: I don't have 2007 handy to test with at the moment, but the original release was a mess as far as automation was concerned.  A series of service packs fixed some problems and introduced others.  SP3 seems to be the best bet; if you haven't applied that, I would do so and I would consider refusing to support any version of PPT 2007 that hasn't had at least SP1 applied.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if such a refusal is possible. I deal with a diverse user base that can have different OS versions, different office versions, etc. Trying to enforce SP on some of the users probably isn't possible.

Comment: Your call, of course, but pre-SP1 PPT 2007 is simply a disaster.

Comment: I just checked, and this problem also occurs on PPT 2007 SP3, which is what is on my machine.

Comment: I'm not sure if this'll lead to a workaround, but what if you save then reopen the presentation before trying to get a reference to the previously deleted/undeleted shape?  Or (probably more useful), copy everything on the slide, delete, then paste back.   Notice that I didn't say anything about this being pretty. ;-)

Comment: I just experienced a similar problem in PPT 2010 (14.0.7015.1000 32-bit). I had several references to a shape that I deleted programmatically. After undoing the deletion, all my references to the (un)deleted object showed lots of invalid properties (just as in OP's case). However, setting all those references to nothing when (right after) deleting the object, solved the problem. Now I can undo and the object and all of it's properties is accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm in Ppt2007 SP3.  Try as workaround .cut and .paste.  Afterwards I was able to access the other methods/properties. - cheers, www.MSO-dlx.com

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Delete
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "Undo" 'or manually Undo
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).Shapes(1).Cut 
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).Shapes.Paste
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "ABC"
```

Answer (score 0):

so, I can confirm that this is an issue; even in 2010 and found a "cheaper" alternative:

```
Public Sub arf()

Dim arf As Slide
Dim shape As shape
Dim shapes As shapes

Set shapes = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).shapes
Set shape = shapes(2)
shape.Select

shape.Delete
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "Undo"
MsgBox ("shape: " & shape.Name & ",Type: " & shape.Type)

Set shapes = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).shapes
Set shape = Nothing
Set shape = shapes(2)

' Cut and paste makes this work, but not required...
'shape.Select
'shape.Cut
'shapes.Paste

'Set shape = Nothing
'Set shape = shapes(2)

Set arf = shape.Parent
MsgBox ("slide: " & arf.Name)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just now I have successfully solved the problem, share the web page which helped a lot : https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2014/06/24/exception-hresult-0x800a01a8/

The critical point is releasing the object after deleting it,which is exactly as Skovly and sharkTwo did.However,I don't know how to do this using C#,and the link gave me the answer.

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(titleShape); titleShape = null;
```

Just like this.